# Console Application .Net Core TaskScheduler Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-server-2016

I have this console application(.net core 2.0) that is working when we are manually executing the .dll using cmd for ex: "dotnet application.dll"

Now we have tried setting it up in task scheduler(same computer):

**Actions :**

Program/script : dotnet

add arguments  : application.dll

start in       : complete folder path to application.dll(C: drive)

Now when we are trying to run the task scheduler using the same computer
there are no errors showing but it is also not running. We looked into the
event viewer and the history but no actions has been made.

Does anyone have a good idea whats causing the problem?

Thanks!

installed .net core version:
Microsoft.NetCore.App 2.2.6